# Is is possilbe to use environment variables in sudoers rules?

Tags: environment-variables, sudo

For example, there is a line defining the rule in sudoers file:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: $HOME/bin/ls
```

is it valid? If not, is there an equivalent way to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get $HOME to expand to the user who is running sudo, or the user who is the destination of the sudo (root in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

It is invalid. If you want to keep environment variables when running command via `sudo`, uncomment/add the following line, for e.g:

```
Defaults env_keep += "VBOX_APP_HOME"
```